# Decorator Design Pattern tied to same interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have one slight issue with the decorator design pattern. It seems that the decorated objects are tied to the same interface as a standard non-decorated object.

Please see the example of the website line below.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm

In this example the RedShapeDecorator is tied to the shape interface so both the RedShapeDecorator and a standard Circle object can only call the draw() method.

Well what do I do when I want my decorated object to be able to call more then draw(). What if I want my decorated object to have methods like drawBlackAndWhite() and draw3D() both of which are not appropriate to wrap up in the draw() method.

In other words I want to be able to extend the RedShapeDecorator to do the following..

```
redShapeDecorator.draw()
redShapeDecorator.drawBlackAndWhite();
redShapeDecorator.draw3D();
```

But the Shape interaface is limiting me to only calling redShapeDecorator.draw(). How do I solve this?

Comment: Either you add the two methods to the `Shape` interface, or it's not the decorator pattern anymore.

Comment: You probably want facade pattern, not a decorator. Also you, of course, can add methods to your decorator and instantiate it (not as an interface, but as a class), but again - it's not decorator anymore and it's bad practice as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get the question right, but if you want a method `drawBlackAndWhite()`(assuming it's analogue of `RedShapeDecorator.draw()`) you can define additional method in your decorator. To get `draw3D()` method in your decorator you should create a new implementation of `Shape` interface which capable to draw 3D objects(because existing implementations Circle and Rectangle are flat). If you want all these methods in one instance of your decorator put multiple `Shape` fields in it. But you won't be able to call methods `drawBlackAndWhite()` and `draw3D()` by reference with type `Shape` because Shape interface has only one method `draw()`